# Replacing roles between logins with asp.net identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity-2

My system uses 2 user roles: *Admin* and *Supplier*.

I'm seeing some very weird behavior in my authentication which I've implemented with the bog standard ASP.NET Identity templates with little alteration of my own.

What's happening is that if I log in as either an admin or a supplier, everything works fine. If I log out and then log back in as a user from the other role, Identity still thinks the logged in user is part of the first role and so, by my alterations, redirects to the content appropriate for that role instead of the content appropriate for the new one.

Here's my login code:

```
protected void LogIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsValid)
    {
        // Validate the user password
        var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();

        // By default, login asks for email address, but logs in with comparison on UserName,
        // so get the user by the email address and compare against that user's UserName.
        ApplicationUser User;
        using (ApplicationDbContext Context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(Context));
            User = UserManager.FindByEmail(Email.Text);
        }

        // This doen't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(User.UserName, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout: false);

        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                // Store the user's supplier Id (if it exists - i.e. user is not an admin).
                using (ApplicationDbContext Context = new ApplicationDbContext())
                {
                    Session["UserId"] = User.Id;
                    if (User.SupplierId >= 1)
                    {

                        Session["LoggedInSupplierId"] = User.SupplierId;
                    }
                }

                IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
                break;
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                Response.Redirect("/Account/Lockout");
                break;
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                Response.Redirect(String.Format("/Account/TwoFactorAuthenticationSignIn?ReturnUrl={0}&RememberMe={1}", 
                                                Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"],
                                                RememberMe.Checked),
                                    true);
                break;
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                FailureText.Text = "Invalid login attempt";
                ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I made some changes to `IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl` so that the login [should redirect] appropriately:

```
public static void RedirectToReturnUrl(string returnUrl, HttpResponse response)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
    {
        response.Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        returnUrl = HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin") ? "~/Members/Admin.aspx" : "~/Members/Supplier.aspx";
        response.Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
}
```

The web.config file handles authorization:

```
  <location path="Members">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="None">
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
```

And the logout destroys the cookie and such:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var authentication = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    authentication.SignOut();

    HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
    authCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
```

I believe the problem is that the `SignOut()` is being done through the OwinContext which I'm not actually implementing (as far as I'm aware). I can't seem to find any sign out methods on the current user through HttpContext though.

How can I clear the information for one user and replace it with another user's information between logins with Identity?

Comment: `Response.Redirect` throws an exception to stop further execution of the page. In some cases when setting / removing a cookie before the `Response.Redirect` it is not always saved (because of the thrown exception). It could be that case and the FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName` is not actually removed. To avoid this issue, try `Response.Redirect("Login.aspx", false);` where no exception is thrown

Comment: @TasosK. since `<authentication mode="None">` is specified in the web.config file, I hadn't thought about using anything to do with Forms Authentication, but I figured I'd try adding `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` to the logout method before the redirect and that fixed it